# Calculate the e/m ratio using a graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, charge

Doing an experiment with a cathode ray and a Helmholtz coils the $1/r^2$ and $B^2$ points were plotted on a graph
After plotting a graph of $1/r^
2$
vs. $B^2$
, the following results were obtained:

slope = $4.5 \times 10^8 \,\mathrm{T^{-2}\cdot m^{-2}}$

error on slope = $1.3 \times 10^7 \,\mathrm{T^{-2}\cdot m^{-2}}$

y-intercept = $40 \,\mathrm{m}^{-2}$

error on y-intercept = $60 \,\mathrm{m}^{-2}$

Correlation coefficient = 94.2 %
A constant accelerating potential difference $V = 150 \,\mathrm{V}$ was used.

How to go about from here to determine the e/m ratio? my first thought was to take the slope of the graph but I could immediately see that the units of the slope is not $\mathrm{J/kg}$ I found on wiki that eV has also different SI units but cannot find the appropriate.

Comment: What does $r$ stand for?

Comment: One of the things that we never tell science student but is actually important is the convention for typesetting units. Symbols representing quantities are typeset in italics (which comes by default in math-mode or MathJax), symbols representing units are typeset upright (and set off by a thing space), which you can get with `\,\mathrm{m}` among other ways.

Comment: You say you compared the units of the slope to $\mathrm{J/kn}$, but aren't the units of $e$ coulombs?

Comment: -1. Surely the background theory is in the experimental script? Or in your class notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you measured the radius of a cathode ray moving through a magnetic field.  And that you used the accelerating voltage to get the electrons up to speed.

From this, it is reasonable to ask yourself, if I had a cathode ray of velocity $v$ coming into a magnetic field, what would be the Newton's second law relationship between the path of the particles and the magnetic field.

Similarly, what is the relationship between the velocity of the particles and the accelerating voltage?

Using these facts, you should be able to work out an equation for $e/m$